# SQL Server 2005 how do I see what variables are being passed into a proc

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to debug a stored procedure. I'm creating a logtable (just a regular table)  and inserting the stored proc input values into it, however this is in the middle of transaction and my inserts are getting rolled back. Is there any way to commit my inserts that have them saved even when a rollback is issued.

Thanks

Comment: What are you using to manage your transactions?  Is it done in a sproc or in code?

Comment: The transactions are managed within a stored proc.

Comment: Are you able to just move the log table insert above the begin tran statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In code if you are calling procedures in a nested fashion only the outermost BEGIN TRAN ... ROLLBACK TRAN will have the ability to create records that will not be rolled back. However, [SQL Server Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx) allows you to see exactly what Transact-SQL statements are submitted to the server and how the server accesses the database to return result sets.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the SQL Server Profiler to see what is being passed into your procs...

Comment: either that or a bunch of *print*s will do :)

Comment: Yes, a bunch of prints will do it also. :)